# Can't hide desktop icons ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, desktop-icons

I just upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 and I can't hide my desktop icons, I've tried **dconf-editor** and **tweaks** but none of them worked.

- In deconf-editor I've disabled the `show-desktop-icons` option in `org/gnome/desktop/background` but it has no effect on the desktop.

Comment: No, the given link does not answer the question. The question is how to HIDE the desktop icons (not how to make them visible).  I have tried "reverse engineering" the advice given in the link, but it does not work.  Also, using Gnome-Tweaks does not work.

Comment: @Duncan use `extensions` application in menu to hide icons